# Calculate the sum of

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The problem just give me this form$$\frac{1}{1*6*11*16}+\frac{1}{6*11*16*21}+\frac{1}{11*16*21*26}+...$$
And I have to calculate the sum.
But I don't know how to proceed. For that reason I need your help or any recommendation. Thanks in advance

Comment: For a start, in the denominator, each term is having 5 added to it every cycle of addition.

Comment: Usually as a first step, try to decompose $\frac1{x(x+5)(x+10)(x+15)}$ into partial fractions.

Comment: Do partial fractions ... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions(+1%2F((5+n%2B1)(5+n%2B6)(5+n%2B11)(5+n%2B16))) ... It is a telescopic sum

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

\begin{align}
\frac {1}{1*6*11*16}&=\frac {1}{15} \left( \frac {16-1}{1*6*11*16} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{15} \left(\frac{1}{1*6*11}-\frac{1}{6*11*16}\right)
\end{align}

And

\begin{align}
\frac {1}{6*11*16*21}&=\frac {1}{15} \left( \frac {21-6}{6*11*16*21} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{15} \left(\frac{1}{6*11*16}-\frac{1}{11*16*21}\right)
\end{align}

Do you see the telescoping sum now?

Comment: I see that the terms start cancelling out but what would be the last term since this goes to infinity?

Comment: @Mastermind817 It'll be negligible. You don't need to consider it as it will be infinitesimally small.

Answer (score 2):

you need to find $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(5k-4)(5k+1)(5k+6)(5k+11)}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{15}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{15}{(5k-4)(5k+1)(5k+6)(5k+11)}=\\\dfrac{1}{15}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(5k+11)-(5k-4)}{(5k-4)(5k+1)(5k+6)(5k+11)}\\
\dfrac{1}{15}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(5k+11)}{(5k-4)(5k+1)(5k+6)(5k+11)}-\dfrac{(5k-4)}{(5k-4)(5k+1)(5k+6)(5k+11)}\\$$
$$\dfrac{1}{15}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(5k-4)(5k+1)(5k+6)}-\dfrac{1}{(5k+1)(5k+6)(5k+11)}\\=
\dfrac{1}{15}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[f(k)-f(k+1)]\\$$so apply this to find answer
$$\dfrac{1}{15}(\dfrac{1}{1*6*11}-0)$$